# How to run Webpack project on apache server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've got a project that runs fine in the dev server environment, but now I am trying to get it to run on an Apache server.  I ran 'npm run build' on my package.json file ("build": "babel-node tools/build.js && npm run open:dist"), and it created a dist folder with the following files:

- index.html
- main.js
- main.map.js
- main.css
- main.css.map

I placed this folder inside of the htdocs folder in my Apache directory.  I double clicked on index.html hoping it would take me to the home page of the app, but nothing happens.  Not even an error in the console.

Here's the index.html file I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Survey Builder</title>
    <link href="./dist/app/main.8286783e52fd295f2f9e5d678a8a2acd.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="app">
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/app/main.66670fe7523b3b72f307.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Dev server runs on node. However, you could serve any webpack compiled stuff with any web server though

Comment: soooo - what do you think I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, did you start the Apache server? Also double clicking the HTML file will not open the version your server serves. Go to http://localhost and see what's there

Comment: Yes.  Apache is running.  I went through localhost and the correct port.  I do notice that it is loading our favicon icon now.  So, a little better.  It still loads a blank page with no errors though.

Comment: Here is the address I am using:  http://localhost:89/ryan/dist/index.html

Comment: It's possible that Apache does not know where your assets are. Try typing some random text in your `index.html` and see if that shows up. If it is then it's most likely the relative url that you're using for your assets.

Comment: I added random text and it does show up.  The assets I have (the bundle file) show up in the network tab of chromes developer tools.  So, it looks like the files ARE being found.  It's acting like it just doesn't know what to do with the files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

*If you're using React and you're deploying on Apache, you need to know that the path where you place your files in Apache must be reflected in your React routes. So, if you place your production ready React files inside of a folder in your htdocs Apache directory, you must also reflect that path in your routes.  If you dump your production ready files straight into Apache's htdocs directory, it will work out of the box.

I hope this helps...